# Does publishing erotica on Kindle Marketplace require an ISBN, or is an ASIN sufficient?

Tags: kindle, isbn, erotica

I heard a few years back that in order to self-publish erotica there, you needed an ISBN. Is that still true? Or is an ASIN fine?

Comment: Welcome to Writers! Please consider splitting this into two separate questions, Stack Exchange sites are designed so that there's a single answer that can be voted on and accepted per question. (I've temporarily placed this on hold until you can do this.) You may also find our site [tour] helpful.

Comment: 1. You need no ISBN to publish on KDP. I have an erotic book there without one. 2. I think you need to consult Amazon on that.

Comment: Apparently someone wrote a book about that - https://www.amazon.com/Violation-Authors-Navigating-Publishings-Guidelines-ebook/dp/B00U9UD9TA

Comment: You could also try asking on https://ebooks.stackexchange.com

Comment: Wow thank you prosepraise, how have I never noticed the ebooks stackexchange!  Joined.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to what book identifiers are required for Amazon Marketplace;

- No, an [ISBN (International Standard Book Number) is not required to publish an ebook with Kindle Direct Publishing (KDP)](https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/G200644220)
- Yes, an [ISBN (International Standard Book Number) is required for an Amazon paperback or hardback](https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/G201834170) but Amazon can assign these for free, notes below.
- Yes, an [ASIN (Amazon Standard Identification Number) will be assigned automatically when you upload to KDP](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/external/201844590?language=en-US&ref=mpbc_201846060_cont_201844590).  This is simply an Amazon product code.  This will be shared across all formats, ebook/paperback/hardback.  This is assigned as a unique key by Amazon on product creation.

There are no special rules by genre, erotica follows the same rules as classic fiction.

Neither ASIN nor ISBN can be changed, once assigned this is fixed.

### [Paperback ISBNs](https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/G201834170)

KDP can provide you with a free ISBN to publish your paperback. We'll also automatically register your ISBN information with BooksInPrint.com®. This a global database of print books maintained by Bowker (the U.S. ISBN agency) and consulted by publishers, libraries, and booksellers.

The “Publisher” field on your paperback's Amazon detail page will read "Independently published." This free ISBN can only be used on KDP for distribution to Amazon and its distribution partners. It cannot be used with another publisher or self-publishing service.

It's important to some authors to provide their own ISBN because it allows them to choose their book's imprint of record. An imprint is a trade name that a publishing company uses to publish a work. If you use your own ISBN to publish your paperback, you'll be prompted to enter the imprint name as well. The imprint you enter must match either the imprint or publisher name that appears in Bowker (the U.S. ISBN agency).

### Relationships

Each ebook can have a single ASIN, ISBN-10 and/or ISBN-13. The ASIN is only used on Amazon. The ISBNs will be common across all publishing websites, bookstores and libraries.  The ASIN will be common across ebook, paperback and hardcover on Amazon only. A new ISBN is needed for each version of the book. See example [ebook](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Jacqueline-Hyde-Robert-Swindells-ebook/dp/B007D15YSC/ref=sr_1_2?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1523107376&sr=1-2&keywords=isbn%2013);

ISBN-10: 0440863295 for ebook, 0385405081 for hardcover

ISBN-13: 978-0440863298 for ebook, 978-0385405089 for hardcover

ASIN: B007D15YSC